# How can I make the ES6 function generic for the whole project?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6, filter

I have a project in Typescript and I have created a function that is responsible for comparing two arrays of objects by a key and removing from the first array those that do not match in the second.

This is my current code:

```
public async onlyObject() {

        let obj1 = [ 
             { codCountry: 'CO', fileName: 'CO_SER.txt' },
             { codCountry: 'CO', fileName: 'CO_TES.txt' } ];

        let filesSheet = [
             { codCountry: 'CO', fileName: 'CO_SER.txt' },
             { codCountry: 'CO', fileName: 'CO_DAT.txt' } ];

        let onlyObj1 = await this.objectComparer(obj1, obj2);

}

public async  objectComparer(fstArr, secArr) {
      try {
        let only = fstArr.filter(({ fileName: id1 }) => !secArr.some(({ fileName: id2 }) => id2 === id1));
        return Promise.resolve(only);
        
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)        
      }  
}

onlyObj1 = [ { codCountry: 'CO', fileName: 'CO_TES.txt' } ];
```

In this case, it compares the arrays well and filters me by the key fileName. What I want is to make it generic for all objects even if they don't have the same keys. Is that possible? How can I do it?

This is an example of what I want to achieve, passing other different objects with different keys, that the same function returns the same result:

```
let objN1 = [ 
    { code: '1', country: 'Spain' },
    { code: '2', country: 'Germany' } ];

let objN2 = [ 
    { code: '1', country: 'Italy' },
    { code: '2', country: 'Spain' } ];

onlyObjN1 = [ { code: '2', country: 'Germany' } ]
```

How can I modify the `objectComparer` function to pass it the key to filter by? In this case, it should filter by `country`

Comment: I don't understand your goal. Do you want to compare all keys between objects? In your example, you only compare the fileName.

Comment: @JBaczuk The function that I currently have is only valid for comparing these objects through the fileName key. What I want is to adapt the function to compare any object by the key that is chosen. I update with an example.

Comment: One of the reasons for downvoting is that the question is unclear. It is not "scoring wrong". I was also not the one who downvoted, but people are able to vote as they please.

Comment: The only thing I need to know is how to pass the ``objectComparer`` function the key by which it should be filtered (which in this case is just fileName but I want to be able to filter by any value)

Comment: `objectComparer(fstArr, secArr, key)`, then `{ [key]: id1 }` and `{ [key]: id2 }` seems like the thing I'd try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the `objectComparer` function to accept any key and use that to compare objects.

```
public async objectComparer(fstArr, secArr, key) {
  try {
    let only = fstArr.filter(
      (fstItem) => !secArr.some((secItem) => fstItem[key] === secItem[key])
    );
    return Promise.resolve(only);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what I wanted to achieve, thanks, it works fine. I'll see how to ask better next time

Comment: No worries, this site can seem pretty hostile at first, you fixed your question and I understood it, no problem